# Modify null pointer field in struct through reflection in Go

Tags: pointers, go, reflection, null

I'm trying to modify the indirect value of the null pointer field "MyField" through a reflection loop.
I'm getting a panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Set on zero Value.

Any ideas on how to do it?

https://play.golang.org/p/IJvA_J_cD60

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    MyField *string
}

func main() {
    s := MyStruct{}

    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)

    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        valueField := v.Field(i)
        fieldName := v.Type().Field(i).Name
        if fieldName == "MyField" && valueField.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            valueField.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf("some changed name"))
            fmt.Printf("the elem after change: %v\n", valueField.Elem())
        }

    }
    fmt.Print(*s.MyField)
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues with the program.

The field cannot be set because `v` is not an addressable value.  To get an addressable value, create a reflect.Value from a pointer to `s`:

```
s := MyStruct{}
v := reflect.ValueOf(&s).Elem()
```

The program attempts to set a value through a nil pointer. The reflect code is identical to `*s.MyField = "some changed name"`.  This statement will panic if MyField is nil as it is in the question.  To fix this, set a pointer into the field:

```
t := "some changed name"
valueField.Set(reflect.ValueOf(&t))
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ypQ-7YfNnkw)

Comment: Many thanks! In this case I know the field type. What if I wanted to initialize the field with a Empty/Zero value of the type pointed (i.e. empty string in this case)? Any thoughts on that?

Comment: `valueField.Set(reflect.New(valueField.Type().Elem()))`